# numpy.histogram: retrieve sum of weights squared in each bin

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is it possible in numpy (or scipy) to retrieve the sum of weights squared in each bin of a histogram? I'd like to have the error on each bin height in my histograms. For unweighed data, the statistical error on each bin height should be the sqrt(N) where N is the bin height.. but for weighted data I need to sum of weights squared. `numpy.histogram` can't do this, but is there some other functionality in numpy or scipy that can bin an array (e.g. the weights array) based on a *different* array (e.g. the array of values I'm histogramming)? I've perused the documentation but haven't found anything.

Comment: I would start with  [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize)

Comment: I don't get it. Could you put this in more mathematical terms?

Comment: @obachtos Let's say I have an array `x = [2,9,4,8]` and an array of weights `w=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4].` I'll create a histogram with 2 bins with `numpy.histogram(x,weights=w,bins=[0,5,10])`. In the 0th bin, I'll get the 2 and the 4 but a total bin height of 0.1+0.3=0.4 due to the weights. In the 1st bin I'll get the 9 and the 8 with a bin height of 0.2+0.4=0.6. I also want to get the sum of weights squared _for each bin_. That would be .1^2+.3^2 for the 0th bin. the statistical error on this bin height would be sqrt(sum(.1^2+.3^2))=0.316... not sqrt(bin height) like with unweighted data.

Comment: @Alex I've take na look at `numpy.digitize` and it bins the input data, I don't see how it would be able to bin the weights w.r.t. the data - would you happen to have an example, maybe it's just not clicking for me

Comment: The proposal solutions are very slow to me. Have a look to boost-histogams: https://boost-histogram.readthedocs.io/ with the weight storage.

Comment: Yes the solutions here are quite outdated. The original problem eventually led me to develop [pygram11](https://github.com/douglasdavis/pygram11), faster than boost-histogram for large datasets, but not as feature-rich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Alex suggested, [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize) is what you want. That function returns to which bins the entries of your `x` array belong to. You can then use this information to access the correct elements of `w`:

```
x = np.array([2,9,4,8])
w = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])

bins = np.digitize(x, [0,5,10])

# access elements for first bin
first_bin_ws = w[np.where(bins==1)[0]]

# error of fist bin
error = np.sqrt(np.sum(first_bin_ws**2.))
```

The last line then calculates the error for the first bin. Mind that `np.digitize` starts to count at 1.

Comment: perfect - the example with `np.where` is what I needed to see for it to click.

Answer (score 3):

If I may add a complement to @obachtos's answer, I've expanded it into a function that demonstrates then for the full histogram:

```
def hist_bin_uncertainty(data, weights, bin_edges):
    """
    The statistical uncertainity per bin of the binned data.
    If there are weights then the uncertainity will be the root of the
    sum of the weights squared.
    If there are no weights (weights = 1) this reduces to the root of
    the number of events.

    Args:
        data: `array`, the data being histogrammed.
        weights: `array`, the associated weights of the `data`.
        bin_edges: `array`, the edges of the bins of the histogram.

    Returns:
        bin_uncertainties: `array`, the statistical uncertainity on the bins.

    Example:
    >>> x = np.array([2,9,4,8])
    >>> w = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])
    >>> edges = [0,5,10]
    >>> hist_bin_uncertainty(x, w, edges)
    array([ 0.31622777,  0.4472136 ])
    >>> hist_bin_uncertainty(x, None, edges)
    array([ 1.41421356,  1.41421356])
    >>> hist_bin_uncertainty(x, np.ones(len(x)), edges)
    array([ 1.41421356,  1.41421356])
    """
    import numpy as np
    # Bound the data and weights to be within the bin edges
    in_range_index = [idx for idx in range(len(data))
                      if data[idx] > min(bin_edges) and data[idx] < max(bin_edges)]
    in_range_data = np.asarray([data[idx] for idx in in_range_index])

    if weights is None or np.array_equal(weights, np.ones(len(weights))):
        # Default to weights of 1 and thus uncertainty = sqrt(N)
        in_range_weights = np.ones(len(in_range_data))
    else:
        in_range_weights = np.asarray([weights[idx] for idx in in_range_index])

    # Bin the weights with the same binning as the data
    bin_index = np.digitize(in_range_data, bin_edges)
    # N.B.: range(1, bin_edges.size) is used instead of set(bin_index) as if
    # there is a gap in the data such that a bin is skipped no index would appear
    # for it in the set
    binned_weights = np.asarray(
        [in_range_weights[np.where(bin_index == idx)[0]] for idx in range(1, len(bin_edges))])
    bin_uncertainties = np.asarray(
        [np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(w))) for w in binned_weights])
    return bin_uncertainties
```